# dojo data grid in custom widget is not rendering

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

hi all i have created a custom widget which in the future will contain more than a data grid however i have had considerable difficulty trying to get the data grid to render.

I have no errors and all the following seems to be being called as i suspect; perhaps it is an asynch issue?

Any help on this would be great, my code as followed.

AssetGridWidget.js

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/_base/fx",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dojo/dom-style",
"dojo/mouse",
"dojo/on",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dojo/text!./templates/AssetGridWidget.html",
"dojox/grid/DataGrid",
"dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore",
"dojo/store/Memory", 
"dojo/data/ObjectStore"]
, function(declare, baseFx, lang, domStyle, mouse, on, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template,      DataGrid,ifilereadstore, Memory, ObjectStore){
return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
    widgetInTemplate : true,
    templateString: template,

postCreate: function(){

     this.layout =
            [
                { name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '100px' },
                { name: 'Color', field: 'color', width: '100px' }
            ];
     this.data = {
                data :
                {items :[
                { name : 'John Doe', color: 'green' },
                { name : 'Jane Doe', color: 'red' }
                ],
                label:'name',
                identifier:'color'
                }
            };

            this._employeeStore = new Memory({data: this.data, idProperty: "name"});
            this._dataStore = ObjectStore({objectStore: this._employeeStore});
      this.grid = new DataGrid
        (
            {
            noDataMessage: "Hazza",
            store: this._dataStore,
             query: { id: "*" },
            autoRender : true,
            structure: this.layout
            },
            "grid" 
        );
    this.inherited(arguments);

},

startup: function() {
            this.grid.startup();
        }

});
});
```

my template is as follows:

AssetGrididget.html

```
<div>

    <div data-dojo-attach-point="grid" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></div>

</div>
```

finally the page i am calling it from

Index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="gridContainer" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script>
require(["dojo/request", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/array", "tartarus/widget/AssetGridWidget", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(request, dom, arrayUtil, AssetGridWidget){

 var gridly = new AssetGridWidget();
 gridly.placeAt("gridContainer");
 gridly.startup();
});
</script>

</body>
```

I have been smacking my head against a brick wall for hours on this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try searching in dom to see if anything is rendering and if so what is rendering ??

Comment: following dom is being created:

<div id="gridContainer" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"><div id="dijit__TemplatedMixin_0" widgetid="dijit__TemplatedMixin_0">

    <div data-dojo-attach-point="grid" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></div>

</div></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `"grid"` as the second argument to the `DataGrid` constructor.  This will attempt to find a DOM node in the document with the ID `grid` and replace that with the grid.

However, based on your template, it looks like what you're actually *intending* to do is to replace your `grid` attach point with the grid instead.  Instead of `"grid"`, your second argument to the constructor should be `this.grid`.

(I might also suggest naming the attach point `gridNode` instead to distinguish it, since you are immediately assigning the actual grid instance to `this.grid` thereafter.)